# Overloading a method using dynamics in .Net

Tags: c#, dynamic, polymorphism, parameter-passing, overloading

I'm a little confused about the "why" of something, and I'd like to get some clarification before this pushes to deployment.

I have a DAL library that is funneling all calls for data to, essentially, two functions.   It's really one function, but I wrote an overload to accept a Data Object, convert it to an `ExpandoObject`, and build query parameters as `KeyValuePairs<string, dynamic>` to satisfy the original function.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ResultSet<T>(string conn, string query, params KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>[] pmts)...

public static IEnumerable<T> ResultSet<T>(string conn, string query, dynamic dao)…
```

My question is this; why is this a valid overload?  Is the `params` keyword what is preventing an ambiguity problem?   Since I'm using  `dynamic`,  and everything works great in testing, I feel I should understand better why this is a permitted overload before it goes into production (lest it explode then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid overload is everything that is different in definition, meaning not exactly the same. This is the case here. There are no more checks in the definition of overloads.

Resolving possible ambiguities take place at the site of use, the applied call.
It's always possible to explictly type each parameter and pick the overload you want in this way.

In case of any type conversions are neccessary and implicitly possible, the compiler will try to find the "Better conversion". Less possible loss of data is always better.

Only if by this selection you end up with multiple overloads with equal-ranked conversions applied, you will get an ambiguity error - at the place of call.

if you call

```
ResultSet<object>("connection", "query", new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("test", null));
```

you will definitly use your first overload, since there is no conversion necessary. No conversion is better than a conversion.